# The maximum level "for" or "of" a thing?

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the following is correct? And why?

> what is the max level of this thing in the game?

or

> what is the max level for this thing in the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both can be used correctly.

If asking after the maximum level a specific item, object, or concept can have, the first sentence is right:

> what is the max level of this thing in the game?

Here, the "thing" can have levels. Having levels is a property *of* the 'thing'.

The second sentence,

> what is the max level for this thing in the game?

I feel could nitpickingly be used when the 'thing' itself has no or doesn't necessarily have levels, but it can be combined with items that have levels, which upgrades the otherwise non-levelable 'thing' (say, a gemstone set into a pickaxe that provides leveled properties to the axe).
In short, here an otherwise independently existing entity provides a level *for* the 'thing'.